# I want to change background and color in magento2.2.6

Tags: magento2.2

I created a custom theme so I want to change change entire background color of website, please help me to resolve it, thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to change the css properties in magento custom theme .

1.Magento2 uses less files so there are already defined variable for primary and secondary color from there you can change the variables for different colors.

2.For custom theme css create a directory
**app/design/frontend/{{Vendor_Namespace}}/{{Theme_Name}}/web/css/source/_extends.less**

here you can write the properties you want for any css classes.
small example:

```
.panel.header {
background-color: white !important;  
}
```

rendering the changes use grunt or `setup:static-content:deploy -f`